# How to use gdal2tiles in python and skip/exclude blank tiles

Tags: python, tiles, gdal2tiles

I am using gdal2tiles in python. It all works well. In gdal the flag `-x` can be used to ignore empty tiles, however in the gdal2tiles documentation there does not appear to be an option for this functionality.

The python library works like this:

```
gdal2tiles.generate_tiles('input_file', 'output_dir/', **options)
```

Various options are available, I use it like so:

```
    options = {'zoom': [zoom_min, zoom_max],
               'nb_processes': nb_processes,
               'resume': resume,
               'tile_size': tile_size,
               'verbose': verbose,
               'webviewer': webviewer
        }
    
    gdal2tiles.generate_tiles(source_path, destination_path, **options)
```

Is there an option like `'ignore_blank_tiles': True`?

Comment: You mean probably this utility https://pypi.org/project/gdal2tiles/. Did you open this issue a few hours ago https://github.com/tehamalab/gdal2tiles/issues/18?

Comment: Yes I did, I went through the actual code of gdal2tiles and I could not find a way to pass an exclude flag , so I though it best to raise with those who maintain the library in case this was an oversight or if I've missed something.